# When user is not logged in redirect to login. Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redirect, ecmascript-6, routes

My App looks like:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    <Router>
      <div>
      <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
      <Route exact path='/game' component={GameContainer} />
      <Route exact path='/chat' component={ChatContainer} />
      <Route exact path='/info' component={InfoContainer} />
    </div>
    </Router>  
  }
```

If the user visits a page under /game and is not logged in, I want to redirect them to the login
page.

**How to do it an elegant way in all routers?**

Comment: Add a onEnter =()={} prop to each route that will take care of authentication. There you write the authentication logic.
onEnter: (nextState, replace) => {
//do the authentication logic here
}

For react router 4 use life cycle methods .

Comment: I use this code to every page that wants to authenticate and work very well:

     if (!this.props.isLoggedIn) {
        return <Redirect to="/login"/>
    }
      else{  
       return //default page code ...
  }

And I can use it in login page if the user is already logged in don't display the login page again

Answer (score 133, accepted):

See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43171515/208079. Perhaps someone with more rep than me can mark this as a duplicate.

The basic idea is to wrap routes that require authentication with a custom component (PrivateRoute in the example below). PrivateRoute will use some logic to determine if the user is authenticated and then either; allow the requested route to render, or redirect to the login page.

This is also described in the react-router training docs at this link https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow.

Here is an implementation using the above as inspiration.

In App.js (or where your routing is happening)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import PrivateRoute from './PrivateRoute'
import MyComponent from '../src/MyComponent'
import MyLoginForm from '../src/MyLoginForm'

<Router>
  <Route path="/login" component={MyLoginForm} />
  <PrivateRoute path="/onlyAuthorizedAllowedHere/" component={MyComponent} />
</Router>
```

And the PrivateRoute Component

```
// This is used to determine if a user is authenticated and
// if they are allowed to visit the page they navigated to.

// If they are: they proceed to the page
// If not: they are redirected to the login page.
import React from 'react'
import AuthService from './Services/AuthService'
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {

  // Add your own authentication on the below line.
  const isLoggedIn = AuthService.isLoggedIn()

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        return isLoggedIn ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
        )
      }
    />
  )
}

export default PrivateRoute
```

Comment: if we are using object of routes then how can we create a protected route.

const routes = {
  path: '/',
  childRoutes: [
    { path: '/login', component: Login},
    {
      path: '/transaction',
      component: Transaction,
    },
    { path: '*', component: PageNotFound }
  ]
}

Comment: Out of curiosity has anyone come up with a clean way to do the _reverse_ of what OP is asking? i.e. how to declare a route like `/login` that is _only accessible_ if the user is NOT logged in/authenticated?

Comment: @mecampbellsoup you'll notice he passes a props.location value into his Redirect so that get's set in the props of the login page and can be used to redirect. I handle that like this (sorry if it doesn't format well as a comment): `class Login extends Component { constructor(props) { super(props); this.state = { from: props?.location?.state?.from?.pathname ?? '/', }; }
render() {
    return userIsAuthenticated() ? (
      <Redirect to={this.state.from} />
    ) : (
      <div />

Comment: How do I implement this if a `PrivateRoute` has sub routes?