# react stateless component with connect

Tags: reactjs, functional-programming, reactive-programming

I want to create an auth HOC that will redirect the user or show the component.

ie:

```
const AuthExtender = props => {
    if (!props.logged) return <Redirect to="/login" />;

    return <WrappedComponent />;
}

const authCompWithState = connect(state=>({logged:state.logged}))(AuthExtender);
```

I know this is not right, but this is the idea I want to have:

```
const MembersPageForLoggedOnly = memberOnlyPageHOC(MemebersPage);
```

I tried so many version of a function that returns function, but I can't nail it...

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: are you using react-router? If that's the case, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43171515/8371135) helped me to achieve this functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this code, you can create a `HOC` with just one function and connect it to the store.

```js
const membersOnly = WrappedComponent => {
  
  // render redirect if not logged, else component
  const comp = ({ logged, ...props }) => {
    return logged ? <Redirect /> : <WrappedComponent {...props} />
  }

  // connect it to store
  return connect(state => ({logged: state.logged}))(comp)
}

// render
const HomePageMembersOnly = membersOnly(HomePage)
```

you could also compose it separatly.

```js
const membersOnly = WrappedComponent => ({ logged, ...props }) => {
  return logged ? <Redirect /> : <WrappedComponent {...props} />
}

// use it directly
const MembersOnlyHomePage = connect(state => ({logged: state.logged}))(membersOnly(HomePage))
```

fyi remember to always pass unused `props` to your `WrappedComponent`.

Answer (score 0):

The usual usage of HOC I have seen is it returns a class:

```
const authExtender = WrappedComponent => {
   return class extends Component {
     render() {
       if(!this.props.loggedIn) {
         return <Redirect to={'/login'} />;
       }

       return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
     }
   }
};
```

And then:

```
export default authExtender(SomeComponent);
```