# How to implement authenticated routes in React / Ant Design Pro

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-router, antd, ant-design-pro

I want to be able to perform:

```
router.push('/compose')
```

And if not logged user will be redirected to the login page and from there to /compose.
I'll be happy to learn a generic React solution or a specific Ant Design Pro solution.
I know that And Design Pro have AuthorizedRoute but I don't know if it can allow this.

I'm using react-router 4.3.1 and antd 3.23.6.

Thanks

EDIT:

It probably needs to be something like @tyler-mcginnin [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43171515/664160):

```
function PrivateRoute ({component: Component, authed, ...rest}) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => authed === true
        ? <Component {...props} />
        : <Redirect to={{pathname: '/login', state: {from: props.location}}} />}
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use React-router and then a conditional to do that. If I had a isAuthenticated variable, set to either true or false, passed into props it would look like this:

```
    let routes = (//unauthenticated routes
        <Switch>
            <Route path = "/auth" component = {Auth} />
            <Redirect to = "/auth" />
        </Switch>
    )

    if(props.isAuthenticated){ //authenticated routes
        routes  = (
            <Switch>
                <Route path = "/manager" component = {DataManager} />
                <Route path = "/logout" component = {Logout} />
                <Redirect to = "/visualiser" />
            </Switch>
        )
    }
```

Update based on comments:

Then in your auth component make a variable that sets the authRediect variable and then render that in your JSX. Something like this:

```
    // This sets up a <Redirect> component so that if the state isAuthenticated is true it will not show the /auth page and isntead will redirect to the desired component:
    let authRedirect = null;
    if (props.isAuthenticated) {
        authRedirect = <Redirect to = "/visualiser" />
    };
...

    return(
            <React.Fragment>
                    {/*The line below performs an auth redirect if the user is authenticated*/}
                    {authRedirect}
                    <h1>Welcome </h1>
            </React.Fragment>
    );
```

So basically you just return the authRedirect variable conditionally based on whether your state is set to an authenticated state or not.

Comment: I did not want to put too much code in, but if you need more context let me know and I can beef it up.

Comment: thanks @Snek, I also need it to redirect to the target component after login

Comment: Hi @kambi, Once you have logged in your auth state would change which would cause a re-render. That means the if(props.isAuthenticated) would be  run again and therefore the redirect at the bottom of the switch block would take place. Does that help?

Comment: hi @Snek, thanks, I understand that the rerender will show the router after login, but I want it to automatically redirect me to there after login

Comment: Ah I see where the gap is. I have updated my answer. Bascially you just need to create an authenticated view and then render that based on your auth state.