# How to design the architecture of a React application?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm an (almost-)React beginner relaunching the site of our Tennis club as an exercise. I have a public site but also an internal area which is restricted to members.

I already created and designed the public part with Router etc but now I wonder how I design it to switch to the internal area: After clicking "Login" I'll have a different menu and different colors etc which means that I have a different routing as well.

Should I plan this altogether in a single page app or is it better to go with two? How?

Thank you for any recommendation.

Best
Conny

Comment: https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-protected-routes-authentication/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement authenticated routes in React Router 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43164554/how-to-implement-authenticated-routes-in-react-router-4)

Comment: Thanks for the blog, it's **very helpful**. Also thanks for redirecting me to the proper similar question/answer!