# map redux state to prop in authenticated react route component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

I have tried to create an authenticated route component to wrap my react routes which redirects to '/' path if login is not valid. I was following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43171515/6716062

However I would like to access my redux store. How can I access the loginStatus prop which I want to inject into props? With the following code props.loginStatus is undefined

Thanks

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { SUCCESS } from '../common/webUtils';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

function AuthRoute( {component: Component, ...rest} ) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={ (props) => props.loginStatus === SUCCESS
      ? <Component {...props} />
      : <Redirect to={{pathname: '/', state: {from: props.location}}} />}
  />
  )
}

function mapStateToProps( state ) {
  return {
    loginStatus: state.userReducer.loginStatus
  }
}

export default connect( mapStateToProps )( AuthRoute );
```

Comment: `loginStatus` is not being passed in `AuthRoute` props. It should work if you add it.

Comment: You can use selectors to access the props from redux store, but you need to pass them as mentioned by @alewis729

Answer (score 0):

Access `loginStatus` from the *correct props object*, in this case `rest`, contains the `loginStatus` prop passed from the `connect` HOC. You can also factor the code a bit to do the check *outside* what is being returned. `Route` only passes the [route-props](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props) to `component`, `render`, or `children`.

```
function AuthRoute( {component: Component, loginStatus, ...rest} ) {
  const authenticated = loginStatus === SUCCESS;
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(routeProps) => authenticated
        ? <Component {...routeProps} />
        : <Redirect to={{pathname: '/', state: {from: props.location}}} />
      }
  />
  )
}

function mapStateToProps( state ) {
  return {
    loginStatus: state.userReducer.loginStatus
  }
}

export default connect( mapStateToProps )( AuthRoute );
```