# Rendering two different components with Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've 2 different components, and I would like to render them separately. Logic is simple when **user is logged in render 1st component**, **if it's not render default component**.

Please review my code, and help me with this, I'm not good at react, so please help me

```
export default function App(props) {
     const Authenticated = props.Authenticated
     const RoutingCabinet = (
         <React.Fragment>
             <Header/>
             <Switch>
                 <Route exact path = '/'    component = { () => TempBody} />
                 <Route exact path = '/new' component = { () => <ResponsiveDrawer />}/>
             </Switch>
             <Footer/>
         </React.Fragment>
     );
     const RoutingContent = (
         <React.Fragment>
             <Cabinet />
             <Switch>
                 <Route exact path = '/user.test'component = { () => <div>Element</div> }/>   
             </Switch>
         </React.Fragment>
     );
     return(
         <ThemeProvider theme = {Theme}>
             <BrowserRouter>
                 { 
                   Authenticated 
                 ? RoutingCabinet 
                 : RoutingContent
                 }
             </BrowserRouter>
         </ThemeProvider>
     );
}
```

Currently I can see only **RoutingCabinet**

Here is the index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(<App Authenticated = {false} />, document.getElementById('__body__', '__root__'));
```

Comment: use a redirect below your route component. maybe It would help

Comment: It's not working, I've tried redirect already

Comment: Can you show how you pass props to `App`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement authenticated routes in React Router 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43164554/how-to-implement-authenticated-routes-in-react-router-4)

Comment: Also, this two different components contains different elements, such as `<Header>` `<Footer>` and etc, by logic when user access to **Cabinet**  he must see `<Header>` and `<Footer>` of **Cabinet** but not the default `<Header>` `<Footer>`

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong here, but is `<Cabinet />` the same as `<RoutingCabinet />`? If so, it might work ok. The `<div>Element</div>` will be visible only if url matches `user.test`. If you are on any other page, this won't be rendered, so it'll look like `<RoutingCabinet />` is rendered, while in fact it's `<RoutingContent />`, it just renders the same output.