# React routing within another component V6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-component

Im using Reavt V6 route.

Im struggeling to get my routes inside gamecomponent to work.

visiting /test results in a completly blank page. while it should load crime module within gamecomponent.
visiting / renders gamecomponent, but /test does not render gamecomponent and the route within that.

How do i make this to work?

visiting url /crime should result in `gamecomponent` beeing loaded, and that

```
<Route path="/test" element={<Crime />} />
```

should be loaded.

app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import GameComponent from './gameComponent.jsx';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Routes, Route, Navigate, Outlet, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import PrivateRoute from './PrivateRoute';
import Login from './components/login/login.jsx';



function App() {
    
  return (

  <Router>
    <Routes>
       <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
       <PrivateRoute  isAuth={true} path="/" component={GameComponent}  redirectTo='/login'/>
    </Routes>
  </Router>
  );
}
export default App;
```

**privateroute:**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useNavigate  } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from './components/login/login.jsx';
import GameComponent from './gameComponent.jsx';


const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, redirectTo, isAuth, path, ...props }) => {
    //isAuth = false;
    
    if(!isAuth) {
        return <Navigate to={redirectTo} />;
    }
    return <Route path={path} element={<Component />} />
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

**gamecomponent:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
//import Component from 'react-dom';
import SideBarRight from './components/game/sideBarRight.jsx';
import SideBarLeft from './components/game/sideBarLeft.jsx';
import Crime from './components/game/crime.jsx';
import Login from './components/login/login.jsx';
import './gameComponent.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";


class GameComponent extends Component{
 constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
    userData: {
        user: {cash:0, bank:0, weapon:'', username: 'test', locationname: 'Bankok',
        defence: 0},
        rankbar: {rankpercent: 50, rank: 'Mafia'},
        }
    }
    
    
    
    
  }


render() {
    return (
    <div className="main">
    <div className="sidebar left">
                <SideBarLeft/>

    </div>
    <div className="middleContentHolder">
     <Route path="/" element={<Crime />} />
    <Route path="/test" element={<Crime />} />
    <Route path="/crime" element={<Crime />} />
    <Route path="/test2" element={<SideBarRight UserData={this.state.userData} />} />


        <div className="col-8">
            <div className="content">
            <div className="header"><span>Test...</span></div>
            
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div className="sidebar right">
        <SideBarRight UserData={this.state.userData}/>
        </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
    
}



export default GameComponent;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to React Router documents:

> You can render a  element anywhere you need one, including
> deep within the component tree of another . These will work
> just the same as any other , except they will automatically
> build on the path of the route that rendered them. If you do this,
> make sure to put a * at the end of the parent route's path. Otherwise
> the parent route won't match the URL when it is longer than the parent
> route's path, and your descendant  won't ever show up.

You can read more about it here - [Descendant Routes](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/f59ee5488bc343cf3c957b7e0cc395ef5eb572d2/docs/installation/getting-started.md#descendant-routes)

So, you just need to do 2 little changes:

**app.js**

Add `*` to yout path in `PrivateRoute`:

```js
<Routes>
   <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
   <PrivateRoute
      isAuth={true}
      // Here's the trick
      path="/*"
      component={GameComponent}
      redirectTo="/login"
   />
</Routes>
```

**gamecomponent.jsx**

Wrapper `Route` with `<Routes>`:

```
<Routes>
   <Route path="/" element={<Crime />} />
   <Route path="/test" element={<Crime />} />
   <Route path="/crime" element={<Crime />} />
   <Route
      path="/test2"
      element={<SideBarRight UserData={this.state.userData} />}
    />
</Routes>
```

Here´s a code sample: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-nash-0mgho?file=/src/gameComponent.jsx)

You can check it with routes:

`/` => show crime component

`/crime` => show crime component

`/anticrime` => show antcrime component

Comment: It seems like its working to get into the gamecomponent. as gamecomponent loads correctly, but the views is not there. the middleContentHolder is empty.

Comment: looks like it wont show anything within the Routes.

Comment: Hi @MalinPedersen, i did a POC with it and worked fine. It isnt showing the routes for you? like `/crime` ?

Comment: /crime loads the gamecomponent, but nothing in middleContentHolder, where the crime should be loaded. ( you have anywhere we could chat?)

Comment: And if i tell you that i dont know how to start a chat from here (LOL). So, i added a code sample for you.

Comment: will take a look at it now. u have discord? i believe your answer is right tho. just weird it wont work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `element={<Crime />}` you should use: `component={Crime}`.

Check the [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/component) for reference.

In your `PrivateRoute` component, you might want to enhance it using the `<Redirect>` component.

Please refer to the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43164554/how-to-implement-authenticated-routes-in-react-router-4), even has a post with a very good explanation that might help you.

Comment: hmm. changed my element to component etg the crime route. but that dosent make any difference it still wont load. will look at that answer tho.

Comment: will that make any diff in v6 @rleiva93 ?

Comment: If it matches the current documentation of the React Router (https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/component) it won't make any difference.

Comment: unfortunly it does @rleiva93

Comment: You're totally right... Sorry about that...

You might want to check this: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/dev/docs/installation/getting-started.md

I case you haven't figured it out.