# How do i protect certain routes while user is fetching

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

When my app mounts, i try to fetch the user by token, that is stored in the local storage. If the token is valid, i then set the user from response to the store. I want for user to see /profile page, only when the user is in the store. But i don't seem to have any idea on how to implement it. If there is no user in the store AND they are on some 'protected' pages like /profile i want to redirect them to login. But the problem is, at the beginning there is no user in the store, so i can't just check for it, and then conditionally redirect(or not) to other pages when the user reloads the page.

App.js:

```
useEffect(()=> {
    dispatch(preserveUser())
  }, [dispatch])
```

User.sagas.js:

```
export function* handleUserPreserve() {
  try {
    yield put(resetState());
    yield put(setUserLoading(true));
    const user = yield call(
      getItems,
     `query {
      getUserByToken {
        purchasedProducts
        orders
        token
        _id
        email
        firstName
      }
    }`
      )
    yield put(setUser(user.data.getUserByToken));
    yield put(setUserLoading(false));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(setUserError(error.message.replace('GraphQL error: ', '')));
    yield put(setUserLoading(false));
  }
}
export default function* userSaga() {
  yield takeEvery(PRESERVE_USER, handleUserPreserve);
}
```

Initial state:

```
export const initialState = {
  userData: null,
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add another field in state, like `isUserLoaded: false`.
As soon as you receive response from api, mark it as true. Then use both `user` and `isUserLoaded` in your condition for redirection.
If you are using HOC for protected route, then you can modify the conditions to something like below to make it work in your case.

```
function ProtectedRoute ({component: Component, authed, ...rest}) {
return (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={(props) => isUserLoaded === true && !user
      ? <Redirect to="/login" />
      : <Component {...props} /> }
   />
 )
}
```

You can optimize it to your needs but surely you need another variable which will indicate that api has returned a response, and then you can check if the user exist in store or not.

[Read more about protected routes using HOC...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43171515/5427320)