# How can I protect a route in React router

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js

Bhai log ye adnan ka pucha wa question hai jab m usko react sikha ra tha usko questions etc krne k liye m apna account diya tha cz pehly account verify krwany k liye baqaida coding challange pass krna hota tha (khud ko legit programmer show krwane k liye), Lekin ab kiu k log meri profile dekhty hain tu mujhe embarrassment hoti hai ;(

I'm using React with Node & express and authenticating with passport and passport local, I want to know that how can I protect a route in React, I mean I want to show a component only if user is authenticated and otherwise I want it to redirect on login page.

In my case I want to protect **Notes** route,
The method I'm trying is not working at all...

**My React Code**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

import Register from './Components/Register';
import Login from './Components/Login';
import Notes from './Components/Notes';


function App () {


  //Function to check authentication from server
  const checkAuth = () => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/notes', { withCredentials : true })
    .then(res => res.data)
  }


  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={Register} />
      <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />

      <Route exact path='/notes' render={() => {
         return checkAuth()? (
             <Notes />
           ) : (
             <Redirect to="/login" />
           )
      }} />
    </Switch>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**And My server side code**

```
//Notes Page
router.get('/notes', (req, res) => {
    if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
        res.send(req.user.email);
    }else{
        res.send(false);
    }
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement authenticated routes in React Router 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43164554/how-to-implement-authenticated-routes-in-react-router-4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider showing a loader until the api call returns a value. Once the api call has returned a value then render the required component using a higher order component.

**App.jsx**

```
class App extends Component {

state = {
    login: false,
    loading: false,
}

componentDidMount() {
    //Function to check authentication from server
    this.setState( {loadnig:true}, () => {
    this.checkAuth()
    }
}

checkAuth = () => {
    // API request to check if user is Authenticated
    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/notes', { withCredentials : true })
    .then( res => {
        console.log(res.data);
        // API response with data => login success!
        this.setState({
            login: true,
            loading:false
        });
    });
    .catch( error => {
        console.error(error);
        // Handle error
        this.setState({
            loading:false
        });
    });
}


render() {
    let {login, loading} = this.state
    let protectedRoutes = null;
    
    if(loading){
      return <loader/>
    }

    return (
        <Switch>
            //use authorize HOC with three parameters: component, requiresLogin, isLoggedIn
            <Route exact path='/path' component={authorize(component, true, login)} />
            <Route exact path='/' component={Register} />
            <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
        </Switch>
    );
}
};

export default App;
```

Using a Higher Order Component will give you the flexibility to control routes based on the login status of the users.

**Authorize,jsx**

```
export default function (componentToRender, requiresLogin, isLoggedIn) {

  class Authenticate extends React.Component<> {
  render() {
      if (requiresLogin) {
          //must be logged in to view the page
          if (!isLoggedIn) {
              // redirect to an unauthorised page or homepage
              this.props.history.push('/unauthorised');
              return;
              // or just return <unauthoriesd {...this.props} />;
          }
      } else {
          // to be shown to non loggedin users only. Like the login or signup page
          if (isLoggedIn) {
              this.props.history.push('/unauthorised');
              return;
              //or just return <home {...this.props} />;
          }
      }
      //if all the conditions are satisfied then render the intended component.
      return <componentToRender {...this.props} />;
  }

  }
  return Authenticate;
}
```

Also, if you ever decide to add in more conditions for the routing then you can easily add those to the HOC.

Comment: Ok I'm considering to implement this, But before that do you think I should use JWT authorisation instead of this? Because I'm not sure the way I'm doing is a standard.

Comment: I mean I want to know if you have to do authentication for your project then what method you'll use?

Comment: @YousufKalim, JWT is a good way to start out. It is widely used for user auth. You can refer [this](https://blog.logrocket.com/mern-app-jwt-authentication-part-1/) blog post for more info on  JWT. 
This will help you persist the user auth state after he has logged in once.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code below

```
<Route exact path='/notes' render={() => {
         checkAuth()? (
             <Notes />
           ) : (
             <Redirect to="/login" />
           )
      }} />
```

With this code please

```
<Route exact path="/notes">{checkAuth ? <Notes /> : <Redirect to="/login" />}</Route>
```

Comment: it show blank page then, mean'a App component not even detecting this route

Comment: I didn't add the sections that @steff_bdh mentioned above. It should work with useState and useEffect hooks

Comment: that is working but only first time, when I refresh the page then automatically state's value changes to false and it redirects to login

Comment: You can persists logged in state by storing a value in localstorage

Comment: For example; inside checkAuth() function, you can first check for the localstorage value. If it is set and true then you can set the authenticated state to true.

Comment: yes this can also work, but I was wondering if there's an easy method to do that, because storing data to local storage and deleting it after logout is a pain.

Answer (score 0):

checking login status via "server request" takes time! Consider then to create a Class with state!, i'll give you an example below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

import Register from './Components/Register';
import Login from './Components/Login';
import Notes from './Components/Notes';


class App extends Component {

    state = {
        login: false
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        //Function to check authentication from server
        this.checkAuth()
    }

    checkAuth = () => {
        // API request to check if user is Authenticated
        axios.get('http://localhost:8000/notes', { withCredentials : true })
        .then( res => {
            console.log(res.data);
            // API response with data => login success!
            this.setState({
                login: true
            });
        });
    }


    render() {

        let protectedRoutes = null;
        if(this.state.login === true) {
            // if login state is true then make available this Route!
            protectedRoutes = <Route exact path='/notes' component={Notes} />
        }

        return (
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' component={Register} />
                <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
                { protectedRoutes }
            </Switch>
        );
    }
};

export default App;
```

I hope this example will be useful to you.

Comment: Yes this is working fine but only first time, when I refresh the page then automatically state's value changes to false,

Comment: At refresh run again => componentDidMount then it will login again!, if you want the user to stay logged in you can implement different logics... I don't know how your backend works, but usually the server returns you a token that you can go save in the front-end and check if the token is still valid without calling the server every time! if your server follows this logic you could use redux or hooks for better performance.

Comment: can you refer me to an article or tutorial about implementation of tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `checkAuth` since it makes a network call may not return the correct value in time for rendering, what you SHOULD do is create a state for whether or not the user is authenticated and have `checkAuth` update that state.

```
const [authenticated, updateAuthenticated] = useState(false);
```

...
update your checkAuth to update the authenticated state

```
//Function to check authentication from server
const checkAuth = () => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/notes', { withCredentials : true })
    .then(res => updateAuthenticated(res.data)); // double check to ensure res.data contains the actual value returned
  }
```

...
update your rendering to use the state

```
<Route exact path='/notes' render={() => {
     return (authenticated ? 
         (<Notes />)
        : 
         (<Redirect to="/login" />)
       )
  }} />
```

... with this approach you can also set the default in `useState` to true or false and determine whether or not it's your server side code that's giving trouble

... dont for get to call `checkAuth` in a `useEffect` somewhere at the top

```
useEffect(()=>{
    checkAuth()
},[])
```

Comment: this is working but only first time, when I refresh the page then automatically state's value changes to false and it redirects to login

Comment: then maybe you need to check your server m8, it's probably not keeping the user logged in; also in your login page you need to check if the user is authenticated (similar process) and if so then redirect to the home page, it all depends on how you've structured you application, think about what loads when and you'll get through it, but that's beyond the scope of this question, can't write the entire app for you m8