# How to handle authenticated routes and their redirects after successful auth?

Tags: flutter, navigation, flutter-web, flutter-navigation

**[Flutter Web(Navigator 2.0/Router API)](https://flutter.dev/go/navigator-with-router):**
How to handle authenticated routes and their redirects after successful auth?

e.g.
I have these kind of routes on my system

```
/book/xyz (authenticated user)
/author/abc/book/xyz (authenticated user)
/authentication (non-authenticated user)
/info (non-authenticated user)
```

If user opens this URL directly, I wanted to ask user to login first, at that time route will be redirected to..

```
/authentication
```

**Once logged in, I would like to user to navigate previously opened URL if any else home..**

Seems like this kind of things may help, any thoughts - how we can achieve similar things?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43171515/2145844

I have tried few samples for Navigation 2.0 / Router API, yes I can understand the concepts a bit..

Some of the references, I have looked at..

https://medium.com/flutter/learning-flutters-new-navigation-and-routing-system-7c9068155ade
https://github.com/orestesgaolin/navigator_20_example
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/dev/benchmarks/test_apps/stocks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how to do it using VRouter >=1.2

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:vrouter/vrouter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(BooksApp());
}

class Book {
  final String title;
  final Author author;

  Book(this.title, this.author);
}

class Author {
  String name;

  Author(this.name);
}

class AppState extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool _isAuthenticated = false;

  bool get isAuthenticated => _isAuthenticated;

  void authenticate() {
    if (isAuthenticated) return;
    _isAuthenticated = true;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class BooksApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Book> books = [
    Book('Stranger in a Strange Land', Author('Robert A. Heinlein')),
    Book('Foundation', Author('Isaac Asimov')),
    Book('Fahrenheit 451', Author('Ray Bradbury')),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => AppState(),
      child: Builder(
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return VRouter(
            routes: [
              VWidget(path: '/login', widget: AuthenticationScreen()),
              VWidget(path: '/info', widget: InfoWidget()),
              VGuard(
                beforeEnter: (vRedirector) =>
                    authenticationCheck(context, vRedirector: vRedirector),
                stackedRoutes: [
                  VWidget(
                    path: '/',
                    widget: BooksListScreen(books: books),
                    stackedRoutes: [
                      VWidget(
                        path: r'book/:bookId(\d+)',
                        widget: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                          return BookDetailsScreen(
                            book: books[int.parse(context.vRouter.pathParameters['bookId']!)],
                          );
                        }),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  VWidget(
                    path: '/authors',
                    widget: AuthorsListScreen(authors: books.map((e) => e.author).toList()),
                    stackedRoutes: [
                      VWidget(
                        path: r'/author/:authorId(\d+)',
                        widget: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                          return AuthorDetailsScreen(
                            author: books[int.parse(context.vRouter.pathParameters['authorId']!)]
                                .author,
                          );
                        }),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> authenticationCheck(BuildContext context, {required VRedirector vRedirector}) async {
    if (!Provider.of<AppState>(context, listen: false).isAuthenticated) {
      vRedirector.to('/login', queryParameters: {'redirectedFrom': '${vRedirector.toUrl}'});
    }
  }
}

class AuthenticationScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Provider.of<AppState>(context, listen: false).authenticate();
          context.vRouter.to(context.vRouter.queryParameters['redirectedFrom'] == null
              ? '/'
              : context.vRouter.queryParameters['redirectedFrom']!);
        },
        child: Text('Click to login'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class InfoWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text('Some info but actually there is nothing'),
    );
  }
}


class BooksListScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Book> books;

  BooksListScreen({required this.books});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          for (var book in books)
            ListTile(
              title: Text(book.title),
              subtitle: Text(book.author.name),
              onTap: () => context.vRouter.to('/book/${books.indexOf(book)}'),
            )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AuthorsListScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Author> authors;

  AuthorsListScreen({required this.authors});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () => context.vRouter.to('/'),
            child: Text('Go to Books Screen'),
          ),
          for (var author in authors)
            ListTile(
              title: Text(author.name),
              onTap: () => context.vRouter.to('/author/${authors.indexOf(author)}'),
            )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BookDetailsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final Book book;

  BookDetailsScreen({required this.book});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(book.title, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                context.vRouter.to('/author/${context.vRouter.pathParameters['bookId']}');
              },
              child: Text(book.author.name),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AuthorDetailsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final Author author;

  AuthorDetailsScreen({required this.author});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(author.name, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The trick is to use a `VGuard` which, before entering the `stackedRoutes`, checks whether or not the user is authenticated.

I used `queryParameters` to store where the user it redirected from, however you could use `historyState` if you did not want where the user is redirected from appear in the url. That being said, I still prefer `queryParameters` in that case since is allows link sharing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [qlevar_router](https://pub.dev/packages/qlevar_router#nested-navigation) to do this.
from the example, in the link, you can define a **Middleware** with **redirectGuard** to check if the user can access this page or its children, otherwise just give the route to redirect to.
you can see this in the [example](https://qlevar-router.netlify.app/#/parent) project too.
if you give the right to access to `Child 4` it will go to `Child 4` otherwise you will be navigated to `Child 2`.