# React route if user hasn't confirmed email

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have a check for email(backend java), and component which displays whether the user has confirmed mail or not, only text confirmed or no.

And I want to force user with not verified email verify email first before using private routes, or any backend features that require authorization.

But i understand where should i add a check like this. I would like this to work at the level of the whole applicationю

My stack react, redux, saga

I would be very grateful for your advice

I tried add to private route this:

```
if (props.state.profile.emailVerified) {
          return (
            <Redirect
              to={{ pathname: '/activate', state: { from: props.location } }}
            />
          );
        }
```

but its not work for me

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

Let's say you have the following routes:

```
<Route exact path='/' exact component={Home} /> // has to be protected
<Route exact path='/settings' exact component={UserSettings} /> // has to be protected
<Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
<Route exact path='/register' component={Register} />
```

In order to check email, you need to create a custom Route, that checks if its authenticated
You cand do something like this:

```
function PrivateRoute (props) {
  // if not verified, redirect to login page
  if (!props.state.profile.emailVerified) {
    return <Redirect to={{pathname: '/login', state: {from: props.location}}} />
  }
  // if verified, render component
  return <Route {...props}/>
}
```

Now that it is created, you can use it on your routes, like this:

```
// changed name from Route to PrivateRoute
// pass the state variable so we can check if the email is verified
<PrivateRoute state={state} exact path='/' exact component={Home} /> // has to be protected
<PrivateRoute state={state} exact path='/settings' exact component={UserSettings} /> // has to be protected
<Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
<Route exact path='/register' component={Register} />
```

For us to give you a proper answer, you need to tell what are you using for routing.
Assuming you are using [react-router](https://reactrouter.com/), you can read the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43164554/how-to-implement-authenticated-routes-in-react-router-4)
if you are using other way for routing, please tell us

Comment: If I understand correctly then I am using react router dom, sorry, I just started learning react

Comment: it's ok, we all been through this. But I insist that you read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43171515/4200834). It is the perfect answer for your question

Comment: I've edited my answer, see if it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

One way can be:

1)tracking email verification with a component in root of your app

2)if user has not verified his/her email yet and user is not already in specified page. (you can use `window.location.pathname` for checking the current route)

3)Redirect the user to the specified route with the help of `useHistory` or with `this.props.history` depending on the way you use react.