# Trying to create an authentication flow using a React navigation bottom tab whereby some screens are open while some need login

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I'm trying to create an authentication flow with React navigation bottom tab, whereby a user can access some screens on the bottom tab navigation while some screens require login. Also i'm trying to make all the screens to be authenticated once a user logs into one screen.

Here is the project

https://github.com/kennymanman/firebase-app

Comment: You want him to be able to see the tab but when he presses it to move him to login? or you want the tab to not be visible at all if youre not logged in?

Comment: I want the bottom tab to show some screens but require login for some, once authenticated it opens all locked screens

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43164554/how-to-implement-authenticated-routes-in-react-router-4
You might want to create your own route and implement some kind of guard with it