# Error: [Home] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>

Tags: reactjs

Hello fellow friends I am trying to create my own app but facing issues after updating the react-router-dom to 6.02 I am getting this error

> Error: [Home] is not a Route component. All component children of
> Routes must be a Route or <React.Fragment>

the code is the following

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar/Navbar";
import Home from "./pages/home/Home";
import Login from "./pages/login/Login";
import Signup from "./pages/signup/Signup";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
          <Navbar />
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/">
              <Home />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/login">
              <Login />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/signup">
              <Signup />
            </Route>
          </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: you need to include the Home component code... otherwise we would be just guessing

Comment: it's just a function component rendering a div

Comment: have you tried surounding the return value with a react fragment? just like the error says

Comment: even so you need to provide all relevant code.  its a policy in stackoverflow to provide a fully reproducible example

Comment: Yes I have tried to add the React.Fragment but that hasn't helped that's why I turned to here.

Comment: Tiko has given the correct answer

Comment: @NewInTown if it worked, i would appreciate if you chose my answer as the correct one

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
<Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
```

This change is necessary because react-router 6 reserves the child prop of `<Route>` for nesting routes.

[Migrating to v6](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.18.0/upgrading/v5)

Comment: Can you please expand this answer with some explanation as to why that code is needed vs the other code?

Comment: In v5, you had to be very explicit about how you wanted to nest your routes and links. In both cases,
In order to use v6, you'll need to convert all your <Switch> elements to <Routes>

https://reactrouter.com/en/6.9.0/upgrading/v5#upgrade-all-switch-elements-to-routes

Answer (score 24):

React router package has some sort of code changes with respect to the versions.

```
// React router v4 or v5
<Route path="/" component={Home} /> 

// React router v5.1
<Route exact path="/">
    <Home />
</Route>

// React router v6
<Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
```

For more: [React Router - Upgrading to V6](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5)

So, you can use V6 syntax to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 8):

This error happens because of the new Upgrade of the react-router-dom library.

**This is the solution to your problem.**

```
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

        function App() {
      return (
  <div className="App">
    <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
        <Route exact path='/' element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='/register' element={<Signup />} />
        <Route path='/Login' element={<Login />} />
        </Routes>
    </Router>
  </div>
       
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

**This is the solution for this version** `"react-router-dom": "^6.0.2",`

Note:- There are some more features than this in the new version of `react-router-dom`.
https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6

Answer (score 2):

i have the same problem too,if you use v6
try not to use close tag for route and use element property to define your component,for examole for the Home rout you should do this

```
<Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed for multiple components under same `Route`. Wrap multiple components inside `<>` and `</>` tags.

```
<Route exact path="/" element={<><AddTodo addTodo={addTodo} /><Todos todos={todos} onDelete={onDelete} /></>} />
```

Answer (score 1):

Uncaught Error: [Home] is not a  component. All component children of  must be a  or `<React.Fragment>`
Solution

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For v6, if you intention is to have a single file containing all Routes for your application, the following should work for you as others already commented.

```
const AppRouter = () => (
  <Routes>
    <Route path='/home' element={<Home />} />
    <Route path='/user' element={<User />} />
  </Routes>
)
```

if you need a different file handling the routes for a subsection of your application, you have to do the following update to `AppRouter`

```
-<Route path='/user' element={<User />} />
+<Route path='/user/*' element={<UserRoutes />} />
```

and your `UserRoutes` should look like this

```
const UserRoutes = () => (
  <Routes>
    <Route index path='/' element={<UserHome />} />
    <Route path='/settings' element={<UserSettings />} />
  </Routes>
)
```

Check the [docs about nested route](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/faq#how-do-i-nest-routes-deep-in-the-tree)