# TypeError: meta.relativePath.startsWith is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and this is just a trial for me and I got this error, Can someone help me out??
I've already tried changed route and then I got this error.

**Issue**:

```
TypeError: meta.relativePath.startsWith is not a function
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This occurs when the `path`  prop is NOT a string. Make sure the `path` prop is a string

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just solved this same problem.  The answer was here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69975860/14866475

This is what I had that was causing the error.

```
    <Routes>
      <Route exact path={["/", "/user"]} element={Home} />
      <Route exact path="/add" element={AddUser} />
    </Routes>
```

And this is the fix that worked

```
    <Routes>
      <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route exact path="/add" element={<AddUser />} />
    </Routes>
```

Comment: This won't be called as solving error...

Previously both '/' and '/user' were rendering the element <Home />

Later you changed it to just "/"

The conflict arises when you give multiple paths to render just one component.
But you actually changed the problem and not solved the one that is there.

Comment: `meta.relativePath.startsWith is not a function` can also occur if an object is passed into `path`

Comment: ^ I was doing passing an object to `navigate({ search: searchParams })` where `searchParams` was an object, but needed to be a string. To fix it, I used `createSearchParams(searchParams).toString()` in place of `searchParams`.

Answer (score 7):

This error just showed up to me and it seems there are no real solutions for this problem since I made the research with no results.

I used to have my code like this, like having several routes in an array inside the path prop.

```
<Route exact path={['search', '/images', '/news', '/videos']} element={<Results />} />
```

Once I was aware there were no solutions on internet I just split every route in a single line each.

```
    <Route exact path='/search' element={<Results />} />
    <Route exact path='/images' element={<Results />} />
    <Route exact path='/news' element={<Results />} />
    <Route exact path='/videos' element={<Results />} />
```

This might not be a good solution for this but it's an option if you want to keep with your work.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me , try this out

```
<Route path="/" element={<Navigate replace to="/search" />} />
```