# I am getting this error in react Error: [News] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Here is my app.js code
I have installed react-router dom version 6 and used routes instead of swicthes still i am getting this error. I also tried to put react.fragment under routes but still the error was not gone. Please help as I am new to react

```
import './App.css';
import React, { Component,} from 'react'
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar';
import News from './Components/News';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";


export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
          <Navbar />

          <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/business"> <News key="business"  country="in" category="business" /></Route>
            <Route exact path="/entertainment"><News key="entertainment" country="in" category="entertainment" /></Route>
            <Route exact path="/general"><News key="general" country="in" category="general" /></Route>
            <Route exact path="/health"><News key="health"  country="in" category="health" /></Route>
            <Route exact path="/science"><News key="science" country="in" category="science" /></Route>
            <Route exact path="/sports"> <News key="sports" country="in" category="sports" /></Route>
            <Route exact path="/technology"><News key="technology" country="in" category="technology" /></Route>
          </Routes>
        </Router>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70108430/269694 this seems like the solution to your issue.

Here is also a link to their getting started tutorial: https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/docs/getting-started/tutorial.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, here is the code, I added element attribute in route.

```
import './App.css';
import React, { Component, Fragment, } from 'react'
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar';
import News from './Components/News';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";


export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
          <Fragment>
            <Navbar />
            <Routes>
              <Route exact path="/entertainment" element={<News key="entertainment" country="in" category="entertainment" />} />
              <Route exact path="/business" element={<News key="business" country="in" category="business" />} />
              <Route exact path="/general" element={<News key="general" country="in" category="general" />} />
              <Route exact path="/health" element={<News key="health" country="in" category="health" />} />
              <Route exact path="/science" element={<News key="science" country="in" category="science" />} />
              <Route exact path="/sports" element={<News key="sports" country="in" category="sports" />} />
              <Route exact path="/technology" element={<News key="technology" country="in" category="technology" />} />
            </Routes>
          </Fragment>
        </Router>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```