# React Router throws error with certain component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I would like to implement routing in my project but I keep getting the same error message and can't figure out how to solve the problem.
I want to start with the `MappedCharacters` component and assign it to the `"/"` route. Here I get the following error message: "Uncaught Error: [MappedCharacters] is not a `<Route>` component. All component children of `<Routes>` must be a `<Route>` or `<React.Fragment>`".

I have also set the browser router in Index.js (so that can't be the problem). As soon as I remove the `MappedCharacters` component it works.
So how could I wrap `MappedCharacters` to make routing work?

App.js

```
import "./App.css";
import Header from "./components/Header";
/* import styled from "styled-components"; */
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import MappedCharacters from "./components/MappedCharacters";
import AddFavorites from "./components/AddFavorites";
import SearchBox from "./components/Searchbox";
import { Routes, Route, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const URL = 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character'; /* Das hier ist der API Link in einer Variablen */

function App() {
  const [characters, setCharacters] = useState([]);
  const [hasError, setHasError] = useState(false)
  const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState([])
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState([])

  /* Hier folgend wird von der API gefetched */
  async function fetchCharacters() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(URL);
      const result = await response.json() 
      setCharacters(result.results);
      setHasError(false);
    }
    catch(error) {
    setHasError(true);
    console.error(error);
    }
  }
 /*  Ohne den useEffect klappt das fetchen und rendern der Cards nicht!!! */
  useEffect(() => { 
    fetchCharacters();
  }, []);

  const addFavoriteCharacter = (character) => {
    const newFavoriteList = [...favorites, character];
    setFavorites(newFavoriteList);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
     
      <SearchBox searchValue={searchValue} setSearchValue={setSearchValue} />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/">
          {characters.map((character) => (
            <MappedCharacters
              name={character.name}
              gender={character.gender}
              status={character.status}
              species={character.species}
              image={character.image}
              favoriteComponent={AddFavorites}
              handleFavoritesClick={addFavoriteCharacter}
            />
          ))}
        </Route>
      </Routes>
      <Navbar />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;

/* const CardElements = styled.li`
color: whitesmoke;
list-style: none;
`; */
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

MappedCharacters.js

```
import React from 'react'

const MappedCharacters = (props) => {
  const FavoriteComponent = props.favoriteComponent;
  return (
    <div>
      <li key={props.id} >
        <h1>{props.name}</h1>
        <p>Gender: {props.gender}</p>
        <p>Status: {props.status}</p>
        <p>Species: {props.species}</p>
        <div>
          <img src={props.image} alt="img"></img>
        </div>
        <FavoriteComponent />
      </li>
    </div>
  )
}

export default MappedCharacters
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: \[PrivateRoute\] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69864165/error-privateroute-is-not-a-route-component-all-component-children-of-rou)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: \[Home\] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69975792/error-home-is-not-a-route-component-all-component-children-of-routes-mus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The issue is with this route:

```
<Route path="/">
  {characters.map((character) => (
    <MappedCharacters
      name={character.name}
      gender={character.gender}
      status={character.status}
      species={character.species}
      image={character.image}
      favoriteComponent={AddFavorites}
      handleFavoritesClick={addFavoriteCharacter}
    />
  ))}
</Route>
```

As the error indicates, only other `Route` or `React.Fragment` components are valid children of the `Route` component. Match routed content should be rendered on the `Route` component's `element` prop.

## Solution

Move the `characters` array mapping into the `element` prop.

```
<Route
  path="/"
  element={(
    <>
      {characters.map((character) => (
        <MappedCharacters
          key={character.id} // <-- don't forget valid React key!
          name={character.name}
          gender={character.gender}
          status={character.status}
          species={character.species}
          image={character.image}
          favoriteComponent={AddFavorites}
          handleFavoritesClick={addFavoriteCharacter}
        />
      ))}
    </>
  )}
/>
```

Or abstract the mapping into a React component and pass the `characters` array as a prop.

```
const Characters = ({ addFavoriteCharacter, characters }) => (
  <>
    {characters.map((character) => (
      <MappedCharacters
        key={character.id} // <-- don't forget valid React key!
        name={character.name}
        gender={character.gender}
        status={character.status}
        species={character.species}
        image={character.image}
        favoriteComponent={AddFavorites}
        handleFavoritesClick={addFavoriteCharacter}
      />
    ))}
  </>
);
```

...

```
<Route
  path="/"
  element={<Characters {...{ addFavoriteCharacter, characters }} />}
/>
```

[image: Edit react-router-throws-error-with-certain-component]

Comment: Yes this is it! Thank you very much! I chose the first option and it worked perfectly fine :)

Answer (score -1):

You can do as MrBens says. You could also use a [`Fragment`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html):

```py
<Route path="/">
    <>{characters.map((character) => (
        <MappedCharacters
            name={character.name}
            gender={character.gender}
            status={character.status}
            species={character.species}
            image={character.image}
            favoriteComponent={AddFavorites}
            handleFavoritesClick={addFavoriteCharacter}
        />
    ))}</>
</Route>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the same error message when I insert a fragment and wrap the component with it. I think I did it exactly as you suggested @pigrammer

Comment: @Jannik Make sure you wrap it around the curly braces which surround the map, not just each component